# apt error when installing o upgrading packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, upgrade, 18.04

everything was fine on ubuntu 18.04. But now when i try to install something with `apt`, or just `upgrade`:

EDIT: i run `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken --fix-missing` and i got:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes...
Creando árbol de dependencias...
Leyendo la información de estado...
Calculando la actualización...
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
18 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se utilizarán 0 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
Configurando python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete python3 (--configure):
 instalado python3 paquete post-installation guión el subproceso devolvió un error con estado de salida 4
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depende de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete python3-update-manager (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depende de python3; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gnome-shell (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de netplan.io:
 netplan.io depende de python3; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete netplan.io (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de nplan:
 nplan depende de netplan.io; sin embargo:
 El paquete `netplan.io' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete nplan (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depende de python3; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de update-manager:
 update-manager depende de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.
 update-manager depende de policykit-1-gnome | polkit-kde-agent-1 | lxpolkit | lxqt-policykit | mate-polkit | polkit-1-auth-agent; sin embargo:
  El paquete `policykit-1-gnome' no está instalado.
  El paquete `polkit-kde-agent-1' no está instalado.
  El paquete `lxpolkit' no está instalado.
  El paquete `lxqt-policykit' no está instalado.
  El paquete `mate-polkit' no está instalado.
  El paquete `polkit-1-auth-agent' no está instalado.
  El paquete `gnome-shell' que provee `polkit-1-auth-agent' aún no está configurado.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete update-manager (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depende de python3:any (>= 3.1~); sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gnome-menus (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depende de python3:any (>= 3.2~); sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.
 update-manager-core depende de python3-update-manager (= 1:18.04.11.3); sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3-update-manager' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete update-manager-core (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de gdm3:
 gdm3 depende de gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); sin embargo:
 El paquete `gnome-shell' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gdm3 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden procesar los disparadores de gconf2:
 gconf2 depende de python3:any; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete gconf2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - no se procesarán los disparadores
dpkg: demasiados errores, parando
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 python3
 python3-update-manager
 gnome-shell
 netplan.io
 nplan
 unattended-upgrades
 update-manager
 gnome-menus
 update-manager-core
 gconf2
 gdm3
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
Proceso detenido por haber demasiados errores.
```

EDIT: `apt-cache policy hplip`

```
hplip:
  Instalados: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Candidato:  3.17.10+repack0-5
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-5 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: try `apt-get install -f`  (--fix-broken or --fix-missing)

Comment: i edited the post with the output of your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please run ` apt-cache policy hplip` (and paste output to your question)

Comment: done! i added the output